# TinyMCE loads the content.min.css for each textarea

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

TinyMCE loads the `content.min.css` for each textarea. If I have 6 textareas on a page the same file is loaded 6 times. This slows down perfomance a lot:(

How can I prevent TinyMCE from doing this?

Here is a fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/8ggaab

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the standard approach to loading TinyMCE it will have to independently load that CSS for each editor as each one is in a separate iFrame which is (effectively) like a separate browser window. The way browsers work they can't share the CSS across the iFrames.

If you use inline mode instead the CSS would be loaded once as there is only ever one instance of the editor actually invoked on the page.